# is any way to insert interrupt for ram access in stm32

Tags: stm32

I am encountering a question in my head.
Can anyone tell me is in stm32 a way to place interrupt on specific location of internal RAM?
This means when you read a value from one specific variable, the interrupt triggered.

Please note that this is a hobby question.

Comment: The chip most likely supports that feature; it would be called something like a "data watchpoint".  However, the feature exists for the purposes of debugging, so it would normally be accessed via a debug interface (JTAG, SWD, or similar), rather than from code running on the processor itself.

Comment: it depends: on an M7 you can e.g. configure MDMA streams to trigger on other events, like SPI DMA Transfer complete, which would be used to copy e.g. data from DMA memory to TCM without any core interaction.

Comment: True about debugging feature (Watchpoint). Alternative idea: if you have memory protection unit, you can lock down that address (prohibit reads or writes or however you like it), it will trigger an exception (interrupt). Configuring MPU is a bit of a pain tho, if you haven't done it before.

Comment: Thanks all of you for answers guys. 
That became more clear to me